# Displaying Images in UIWebView

Tags: ios, image, uiwebview

I am updating my app and due to the size of it I want to remove local images and load them through UIWebView. I have been testing it and my code works loading pages though looking around at other tutorials and pages from Apple, it seems there needs to be more code to pull the image alone to display in the UIWebView container.

This is my code:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"My Image URL Here"]]];
```

Could someone please help me with my code so it displays the image? (I have tested this code with google images and it displays the image though with a hep of white space underneath.

Also, I don't know where the best place to upload my images would be. Obviously uploading to a website like flickr or Facebook will load the page not the image by itself. What would be a good site?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use `UIImageView`?

Comment: Also if there is a way to centre the image within the UIWebView container. THANKS!

Comment: @Raptor - My app was getting too big. The images brought the size up to about 120MB, and for the kind of app it is I felt it was using a lot of storage.

Comment: You could use Amazon S3 to host your images. It's very cheap and free up to a certain amount for the 1st year.

Comment: Use   UIImageView for loading images,you load the images asynchronously

Comment: Wait. Loading 120MB image in an App? Watch out RAM & network usage.

Comment: Wait. What kind of images are these? 300 dpi files? Also, are you using Xcode's asset catalog? This reduces image sizes incredibly.

Comment: No they are about 800kb each. They are just JPGs, Just a lot of them.

Comment: Consider converting all those JPGs to PNGs. I find this will reduce your app size considerably.

Comment: @troop231 I think PNGs will increase app size?

Comment: Try @Rose suggestion and research about lazy loading. It will help.

Comment: @sahara108 no, Xcode prefers PNGs and optimizes them..